# LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest,this); Unreachable Statement

Tags: android, location, maps, locationlistener

I've followed the Step by Step correctly for Showing My Location in Maps, however, The same error is LocationListener. in the unreachable statement on RequestLocationUpdates. Whereas previously Import Location Listener from Google Play Service (Library previously installed).

***Here is List Import***

[image: List Import]

***Error***
[image: Error]

Comment: "Unreachable statement" means that the line will never get executed. Often this is caused by having a `return` or `throw` statement on an earlier line.

Comment: "You followed the Step by Step correctly" - I presume you followed some step by step guide. Which one? Either provide the link where you found it, or explain your steps in the question.

Comment: As @Ragnis said, and please provide that block of code in your question.